# highchart change color if defiend rage is high

Tags: graph, highcharts

I have `bar` graph and i want to change color of graph if it goes higher than 500.

following `data: days` is a variable `days` store values from `mysql` how do i define `low:` and `high:` values in following code, I have tried multiple options but no luck

`days` variable hold values like `150, 200, 234, 655, 7434, 222`

```
 series: [{
            type: 'column',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            data: days,
            shadow : true,
            showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
        }]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by pre-processing your data.

Something like this:

```
$.each(dataRaw, function(i,val) {
    if(val < low) {
        dataFiltered.push({"y":val,"color":"blue"});
    }
    else if(val > high) {
        dataFiltered.push({"y":val,"color":"red"});
    }
    else {
        dataFiltered.push(val);
    }
});
```

You have to pre-define your high/low values, loop through your data, and build a data array that includes the color declarations for any values requiring highlight.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/svucekrm/